# Connect to docker container as user other than root

Tags: docker, containers, root

BY default when you run

```
docker run -it [myimage]
```

OR

```
docker attach [mycontainer]
```

you connect to the terminal as root user, but I would like to connect as a different user.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. `docker run --user user_name`

Comment: There is no such option for attach. You'll have to login as root and then `su user_name`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

For `docker run`:

Simply add the option `--user <user>` to change to another user when you start the docker container.

```
docker run -it --user nobody busybox
```

For `docker attach` or `docker exec`:

Since the command is used to attach/execute into the existing process, therefore it uses the current user there directly.

```
docker run -it busybox  # CTRL-P/Q to quit
docker attach <container id>  # then you have root user
/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=10(wheel)

docker run -it --user nobody busybox # CTRL-P/Q to quit
docker attach <container id>  
/ $ id
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nogroup)
```

If you really want to attach to the user you want to have, then

1. start with that user `run --user <user>` or mention it in your `Dockerfile` using `USER`
2. change the user using `su

Comment: got s6-rmrf: fatal: unable to remove /var/run/s6/container_environment: Permission denied

Comment: Well for the `docker exec` it is actually possible to override the user with the `--user` argument. You're attaching to the existing container, true, but not to the existing tty, so the user could be different.

Answer (score 132):

You can run a shell in a running docker container using a command like:

```
docker exec -it --user root <container id> /bin/bash
```

Comment: *root* is the default user. `--user` option can be omitted when commands have to be run as root I suppose.

Comment: @Stphane that's not always the case since the default user can be customized in **Dockerfile** via the `USER` instruction, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Answer (score 17):

As an updated answer from 2020. `--user`, `-u` option is `Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])`.

Then, it works for me like this,

```
docker exec -it -u root:root container /bin/bash
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 7):

You can specify `USER` in the Dockerfile. All subsequent actions will be performed using that account. You can specify `USER` one line before the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` if you only want to use that user when launching a container (and not when building the image). When you start a container from the resulting image, you will attach as the specified user.

Comment: Also never forget to set HOME

Answer (score 2):

The only way I am able to make it work is by:

```
docker run -it -e USER=$USER -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v `pwd`:/siem mono bash
su - magnus
```

So I have to both specify $USER environment variable as well a point the /etc/passwd file. In this way, I can compile in /siem folder and retain ownership of files there not as root.

Comment: Didn't work 'as is' but directed me to working solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This solved my use case that is: "Compile webpack stuff in nodejs container on Windows running Docker Desktop with WSL2 and have the built assets under your currently logged in user."

```
docker run -u 1000 -v "$PWD":/build -w /build node:10.23 /bin/sh -c 'npm install && npm run build'
```

Based on the answer by [eigenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47894556/53864). Thank you!

Also [this](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf) material helped me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_cmds="$@"

GID=$(id -g $USER)
UID=$(id -u $USER)
RUN_SCRIPT=$(mktemp -p $(pwd))
(
cat << EOF
addgroup --gid $GID $USER
useradd --no-create-home --home /cmd --gid $GID --uid $UID  $USER
cd /cmd
runuser -l $USER -c "${user_cmds}"
EOF
) > $RUN_SCRIPT

trap "rm -rf $RUN_SCRIPT" EXIT

docker run -v $(pwd):/cmd --rm my-docker-image "bash /cmd/$(basename ${RUN_SCRIPT})"
```

This allows the user to run arbitrary commands using the tools provides by `my-docker-image`.  Note how the user's current working directory is volume mounted
to  `/cmd` inside the container.

I am using this workflow to allow my dev-team to cross-compile C/C++ code for the arm64 target, whose bsp I maintain (the `my-docker-image` contains the cross-compiler, sysroot, make, cmake, etc).  With this a user can simply do something like:

```
cd /path/to/target_software
cross_compile.sh "mkdir build; cd build; cmake ../; make"
```

Where `cross_compile.sh` is the script shown above.  The `addgroup/useradd` machinery allows user-ownership of any files/directories created by the build.

While this works for us.  It seems sort of hacky.  I'm open to alternative implementations ...

Answer (score 1):

For `docker-compose`. In the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        image: ...
        user: ${UID:-0}
...
```

In `.env`:

```
UID=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute command as www-data user: `docker exec -t --user www-data container bash -c "ls -la"`