# Rootless docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, root, alpine-linux, debian-based

I tried running the latest builds of debian and alpine but seems to run as root user.

I expected `echo $USER` should not return root if it returns empty; then I need to verify with the command `whoami` if that also returns root we have logged into docker container in root mode which can lead to a vulnerability.

Comment: What do you need actually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734474/connect-to-docker-container-as-user-other-than-root

Comment: You can always `docker run -u 0 ...` to get a root shell based on an image, and if you can `docker run` anything then you can `docker run -v /:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` and similar things to trivially root the host.  What are you trying to accomplish, and what do you mean by "rootless"?

Comment: need a debian or alphine based image which can be used for building docker images ,which can be used to make another rootless docker image which can be run by my k8s cluster

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine3.9 AS release when i run create an image using the above image and do  the docker run or deploying to k8s cluster will create a user that is logged in as root  on my cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to deal with this is to override this in your `Dockerfile` (you can do `docker run --user`, but that can be confusing to programs since e.g. there won't be a home directory setup).

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN useradd --create-home appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser
```

More details, and some other things you can do to secure your container: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/root-capabilities-docker-security/

Answer (score 1):

According to this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35736699/7629560), you need to pass the parameter `--user <user>` in order to login as non-root user.

Example: `docker run -it --user nobody alpine`